# Java listen for server - messages getting lost

Tags: java

I am using a thread and a while true loop to listen for message from my server. For some strange reason some messages are getting lost. (I am logging from my server so i am 100% sure that the message is sent, therefore the problem has to be on the client side). This seems to happend when the server is sending messages fast to the client.

Im using the following code to listen for new messages (on my client):

```
        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("url.com"), 8080);
            is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,
                "Could not establish network connection to the server."
                + " \nPlease check your internet connection and restart the application.",
                "Unable to connect",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            WindowEvent wev = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(wev);
            setVisible(false);
            dispose();
            System.exit(0); 
        }

        // Starta thread to listen for messages from the server
        new ListenFromServer().start();




  /*
     * Thread class to listen for message from the server
     */
    class ListenFromServer extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            while (true) {

                try {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                    String tmpMsg = in.readLine().replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n", "");

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(tmpMsg);  

                    if(json.get("type").toString().contains("preview")) {
                                System.out.println("PREVIEW: " + json.get("msg").toString());



                            }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating a new `BufferedReader` to receive each message. If two messages arrive in quick succession, it could pull multiple messages out of `is`, and then you're discarding the contents. Declare `in` outside of your `while` loop (and handle the close condition appropriately).

Comment: @Alosyius If an answer solves your problem, please click the check mark under the score to accept it.

Comment: Had to wait a few mins :) Sorry for the delay

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a ServerSocket -- it listens and handles a queue of incoming connections (default size 50) so that you don't lose connections.  As your code is, if a connection is attempted in the time between one connection getting established and the loop coming around to connect() again, there wouldn't be anything listening.

Comment: In this case, he only has one socket; the problem is that he's got a race condition on his buffer.